# How To Add Description To JCarousel

Tags: jquery

I am using `jcarousel`. I can't add description to photo in slider.

```
<div id="jcarousel">
    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <li>
            <img src="images/about_img1.jpg"/>
        </li>                
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where do you want to add a description? To the photo? Or above the slider (this could be done by plain HTML I guess), or where?

Comment: You can create a div after your jCarousel container and change the content of the div on next and previous button click callback function in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a div after your jCarousel container and change the content of the div on next and previous button click callback function in jQuery. Check this:

```
<div id="jcarousel">
    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <li>
            <img src="images/about_img1.jpg"/>
        </li>                
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="description">
    <label id="caption">First image</label>
</div>
```

In your jquery code:

Keep a data structure, say array for all captions. And change the caption according to image being shown.

Hope this helps.

Comment: and how to change the caption according to the image selected? Can we give the alt text here for the active image?