# How to dynamically append text to images in a carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The carousel in question is elastislide http://tympanus.net/Development/Elastislide/index.html, currently mine is displayed after a search with the results inside the carousel but I have no way to add text text dynamically in order to make it clear to the user exactly what the result is.

```
<!-- Elastislide Carousel and Overlay -->
    <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
    <?php

if(isset($_POST["title"]))
{
  $se = $_POST['title'];
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $sth = $DBH->prepare("SELECT subjects_id FROM subjects WHERE title LIKE '%".$se."%'");
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    $arr  = $result;
    $image=2;
    $length = count($arr);
    for ($i=0; $i < $length && $i<40; $i++)
    { 
        if ($arr[$i]!="") 
          {
              echo'<li><a  id="dummy" href="http://localhost/website/subjects/view/'.$arr[$i][0].'" ><img src="images/small/'.$image.'.jpg" alt="image02" /></a></li>';

              $image++;
          }
    }
} 
?>      

</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">    
( function($) 
  {
      $( '#carousel' ).elastislide();
  } ) ( jQuery );

</script>
<!-- End Elastislide Carousel and Overlay  -->
```

Comment: in your site Result -> is not displayed even after a search with the results inside the carousel.There is no Search button and box

Comment: There is I just didn't include it

Comment: you can make a <div> with position absolute and put it on picture with ccs, I think this is the best way

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm not sure exactly how to go about it but I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22222108/1777090)

You can add a div after image and change its content dynamically.

```
<ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
<div id="description">
    <label id="caption">First image</label>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.