# jCarousel image captions not displaying

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I am using  a jCaraousel on my website to display adverts with a short description. The images are working fine but for some reason the text is not displaying, it looks like this:

[image]

The buttons allow you to scroll back and forth between the images but the labels just dont display.

Here is the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Custom/Supabets/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Custom/Supabets/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel-autoscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Custom/Supabets/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel-control.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Custom/Supabets/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Custom/Supabets/Scripts/Supabets.js"></script>

<div class="homecontent" id="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="banner-carousel">
            <ul>
                <li id="banner-1"><a href="/Account/NewUser.aspx" target="_top">
                    <img alt="" src="/Custom/Supabets/Images/tdDXAdvertRolling_3EasySteps.png" />
                </a></li>
                <li id="banner-2"><a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">
                    <img alt="" src="/Custom/Supabets/Images/tdDXAdvertRolling_MultipleBetSpecial.png" />
                </a></li>
                <li id="banner-3"><a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">
                    <img alt="" src="/Custom/Supabets/Images/tdDXAdvertRolling_MoneyBackBonus.png" />
                </a></li>
                <li id="banner-4"><a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">
                    <img alt="" src="/Custom/Supabets/Images/tdDXAdvertRolling_RegistrationBonus.png" />
                </a></li>
                <li id="banner-5"><a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">
                    <img alt="" src="/Custom/Supabets/Images/tdDXAdvertRolling_FreeDelivery.png" />
                </a></li>
                <li id="banner-6"><a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">
                    <img alt="" src="/Custom/Supabets/Images/tdDXAdvertRolling_SuggestionBonus.png" />
                </a></li>
                <li id="banner-7"><a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">
                    <img alt="" src="/Custom/Supabets/Images/tdDXAdvertRolling_BuyBackBonus.png" />
                </a></li>
                <li id="banner-8"><a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">
                    <img alt="" src="/Custom/Supabets/Images/tdDXAdvertRolling_MobileVouchers.png" />
                </a></li>                
<!--                <li id="banner-9"><a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">
                    <img alt="" src="/Custom/Supabets/Images/tdDXAdvertRolling_MobileVouchers.png" />
                </a></li>-->
            </ul>
            <div class="banner-carousel-controls">
                <div class="carousel-label display-inline-block">
                    <div class="banner-control banner-control-1">
                        <h2>
                            <a href="/Account/NewUser.aspx" target="_top">Easy Registration</a></h2>
                        <p>
                            Three easy Steps!</p>
                        <a href="/Account/NewUser.aspx" target="_top">Read more ...</a></div>
                    <div class="banner-control banner-control-2">
                        <h2>
                            <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Multiple Special</a></h2>
                        <p>
                            Gives you more winnings!</p>
                        <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Read more ...</a></div>
                    <div class="banner-control banner-control-3">
                        <h2>
                            <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Money Back
                                Bonus</a></h2>
                        <p>
                            We give back!</p>
                        <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Read more ...</a></div>
                    <div class="banner-control banner-control-4">
                        <h2>
                            <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Registration
                                Bonus</a></h2>
                        <p>
                            50% extra!</p>
                        <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Read more ...</a></div>
                    <div class="banner-control banner-control-5">
                        <h2>
                            <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Free delivery</a></h2>
                        <p>
                            We deliver to your door!</p>
                        <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Read more ...</a></div>
                    <div class="banner-control banner-control-6">
                        <h2>
                            <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Bonus Suggestion</a></h2>
                        <p>
                            We want your help!</p>
                        <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Read more ...</a></div>
                    <div class="banner-control banner-control-7">
                        <h2>
                            <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Buy Back Bonuses</a></h2>
                        <p>
                            We will do a buy-back!</p>
                        <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Read more ...</a></div>
                    <div class="banner-control banner-control-8">
                        <h2>
                            <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Mobile Vouchers</a></h2>
                        <p>
                            Loaded on Your Mobile!</p>
                        <a href="/Pages/Promotion/Sport" target="_top">Read more ...</a></div>
                    <!--<div class="banner-control banner-control-9">
                        <h2>
                            <a href="http://ls.betradar.com/ls/livescore/?/supabets/en/page/worldcup_single" target="_top">World Cup</a></h2>
                        <p>
                            Win Big in Brazil!</p>
                        <a href="http://ls.betradar.com/ls/livescore/?/supabets/en/page/worldcup_single" target="_top">Read more ...</a></div>-->
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-controls display-inline-block">
                    <a class="jcarousel-next" href="#">
                        <img src="/Custom/Supabets/Images/btn-arrow-up.png" />
                    </a><a class="jcarousel-prev" href="#">
                        <img src="/Custom/Supabets/Images/btn-arrow-down.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('.banner-carousel').jcarousel({
    'wrap' : 'circular',
    'animation' : 'slow'
})

$('#packagegallery').on('create.jcarousel', function(event, carousel) {
    SecretSojourns.packageGalleryAnchor = $(this).children('ul').children('li').first().children('a')
}).jcarousel({
    'wrap': 'circular',
    'animation': 'slow'
});

$('.banner-carousel').delegate('li', 'itemvisiblein.jcarousel', function(event, carousel) {
    var itemIndex = $(this).attr('id').substr(7);
    $('.banner-control').hide();
    $('.banner-control-' + itemIndex).show();
});

$('#packagegallery').delegate('li', 'itemvisiblein.jcarousel', function(event, carousel) {
    SecretSojourns.packageGalleryAnchor = $(this).find('a');
});

$('.popular-packages-carousel').jcarousel({
    'wrap' : 'circular',
    'animation' : 'slow'
})

$('.jcarousel-prev').jcarouselControl({
    target: '-=1'
});

$('.jcarousel-next').jcarouselControl({
    target: '+=1'
});
```

Comment: Where are the labels in your HTML code? I don't see any labels?

Comment: The labels are the "banner-control banner-control-1", "banner-control banner-control-2" etc. divs

Comment: I had a little look at the documentation and it doesn't seem to be built in. I think you're supposed to use the events to do it yourself whenever the image changes. See:http://stackoverflow.com/a/22222108/1031312

Comment: I think that is what is happening in the   banner-carousel.delegation method. The problem lies in the firing of the event, the 'itemvisiblein.jcarousel' event is not firing when the item changes. Its strange because there  is no mention of this  event in the documentation, but the jCarousel is working on several  other of my sites perfectly

Comment: So if you're saying that you've coded it according to the documentation (http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/events.html#visiblein) and it is not working as expected, I would say go for an alternative or if you have time, email the support and wait for a response.

Comment: Here is a popular alternative which I have used before and is easy to set up, and works as expected. Also supports captions. http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider/